# Python not importing modules

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, import

I've got a function here for running an external python script in another process. m is the Multiprocessing module

```
def run(app,WindowOffX,WindowOffY,WindowWidth,WindowHeight):
    try:
        exec("import Programs."+app+".main as Foo")
        Foo.init()
        p = m.Process(target=Foo.main(WindowOffX,WindowOffY,WindowWidth,WindowHeight))
    except ImportError:
        print("That app doesn't exist!!! O.O")
```

But this generates `NameError: global name 'Foo' is not defined`. Can someone help?

Comment: IMHO this is neither a bad question nor too localized. Don't be so downvote-happy, guys! And explain the perceived problem so the poster can try to address it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha, the problem is that python doesn't know your `exec` statement defines `Foo`, so it tries to look it up as a global. To clue it in, try this:

```
    try:
        Foo = None
        exec("import Programs."+app+".main as Foo")
        Foo.init()
```

Incidentally, here's how you can do what you're after without using `exec`:

```
Foo = __import__("Programs."+app+".main")
```